# Iterate with regexp array to find words that contain input current value - instant search

Tags: jquery, arrays, regex, loops, search

I have this jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        $array = ['usa','france','germany'];
        $input_val = $("input[name='native_input']").val();
    });
});
```

That proceeds this input:

```
<div class="search_native"><input type="text" name="native_input" id="native"/></div>
<div id='output'></div>;
```

I need to iterate through the `$array`, find the values that contain in any place of a word `$input_val` and display it in `$output`. How can I do that?
(I try to make simple jQuery instant search - user types and the script looks for matching values and suggest it underneath). It is similar to StackOverflow Tags field - it in real time suggests suitable results.

Comment: So to confirm, if the user types `ger`, you want `germany` to be matched ans displayed in `$output`?

Comment: exactely.! and if just 'g' letter - all countries that contain the letter 'g'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("input").keyup(function(){
        $array = ['usa','france','germany'];
        $input_val = $("input[name='native_input']").val();
        $('#output').text('')
        r = new RegExp($input_val)
        for (i = 0; i < $array.length; i++) {
          if ($array[i].match(r)) {
              $('#output').append('<p class="match">' + $array[i] + '</p>')
          }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
/* Just to make the demo a little prettier */

body {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
}

#output {
  display: inline-block;
}

.match {
  padding: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #333;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="search_native"><input type="text" name="native_input" id="native"/></div>
<div id='output'></div>
```

How it works:

- `$('#output').text('')` clears the list from the previous time the key was pressed
- `r = new RegExp($input_val)` creates a new RegEx to search for the letters typed. E.g. If the user typed `ger`, the RegEx would be `/ger/` (well, technically it would be `/(?:ger)/`, but it is the same thing)
- `for (i = 0; i < $array.length; i++)` creates a loop that will runs exactly as many tiems as there are items in `$array`, basically it loops through `$array`
- `if ($array[i].match(r))` will check to see if the item in `$array` currently being looped through matches what the user typed (using the RegEx `r`)
- `$('#output').append('<p class="match">' + $array[i] + '</p>')` will append the item in `$array` if it matches